# How to replace dataframe text column with only the 1st occuring word / words before a comma

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

The dataframe for the problem statement looks like

| Name | UID | search_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 14 | kj |
| S | 2 | hsa,isd |
| D | 10 | sa,ad,ad |
| E | 99 | pid, pd,dd,ef |
| G | 8 | dd |

I want the dataframe search_text to be stripped and replaced on the 1st word before comma.(I dont want to manually map it and replace). So it would look like.

| Name | UID | search_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 14 | kj |
| S | 2 | hsa |
| D | 10 | sa |
| E | 99 | pid |
| G | 8 | dd |

Is there any convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the first alphanumerics in the string

```
df['search_text'] = df['search_text'].str.extract('(^\w+)')



   Name  UID search_text
0    B   14          kj
1    S    2         hsa
2    D   10          sa
3    E   99         pid
4    G    8          dd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
df['search_text'] = df['search_text'].str.split(',').str[0]
print(df)

  Name  UID search_text
0    B   14          kj
1    S    2         hsa
2    D   10          sa
3    E   99         pid
4    G    8          dd
```